# Prevent multiple form submissions on distributed site

Tags: php, forms, symfony, amazon-ec2, distributed

How do I prevent multiple form submissions on a website which is distributed across several servers, without using 'server stickyness'?

Currently, the submit button & form is disabled client-side on post, but how do I stop it server side? If the form can be posted to several servers (based on load-balancing), I cant match a token if it was generated on a different server to the one receiving the post back.

How can I prevent this without forcing users to always post to the same server?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is off topic for this site probably belongs on ServerFault,

Comment: Please see http://myphpform.com/prevent-multiple-form-submissions.php?wb48617274=D23EA710

Answer (score 0):

Multiple submission in php can be prevented using **JavaScript** and **cookies**

For more info, see http://myphpform.com/prevent-multiple-form-submissions.php?wb48617274=D23EA710